# Is $f \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ compactly supported?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be an open and bounded domain. Furthermore let:

$$H_0^1(\Omega) = \{f \in H^1(\Omega)\,  |\, f|_{\partial\Omega}=0 \}.$$

$f \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ is said to be compactly supported on $\Omega$. Can we prove that? If I wanted to do that then I think I would have to know something about $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^N \backslash \Omega$, but I don't know anything there really, or do I?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Why is $f \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ compactly supported?

Comment: What is your definition of compactly supported?

Comment: I am thinking of the compact support as defined here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the definition you have mentioned the function need not have compact support. Consider $B(0,1)\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and the function $f(x)=1-\Vert x\Vert^2$. The support in $B(0,1)$ is $B(0,1)$, which is not compact.

However, what the author probably had in mind, was that you can extend $f\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ to
$$F(x)=\begin{cases} f(x),& x\in \Omega,\\ 0,& x\in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \Omega\end{cases}$$
see [Extension by zero of functions of H^1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1978417/extension-by-zero-of-functions-of-h1). Now $F$ has compact support, because its support is contained in $\overline{\Omega}$ which is compact. Depending on your point of view you might want to identify $f$ with $F$ and say (by abuse of notation) that $f$ has compact support.

Comment: Many thanks, @Severin Schraven! Do you think that you can extend $f \in L^2(\Omega)$, where $f$ has an essential support on $\Omega$, in the same way?

Comment: @Someone Sure, for $L^p$ this is even easier as you don't have to worry about the derivative. The only thing one needs to check is measurability, but that is not that hard (we have that $F^{-1}(A)$ is equal to $f^{-1}(A)$ or $f^{-1}(A)\cup (\mathbb{R}\setminus \Omega)$ which are both measurable).